# Setting outgoing call to an mp3 music in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Hi i want to make an android app in which when an incoming call come.it will be received and play an mp3 file in the sdcard.i know how to receive the intent of incoming call and pick it up.but in outgoing i have to play mp3 file please suggest some good reference for implementing it.

Comment: play an mp3 file means its only sound in outgoing voice of the user.